# In flutter, json data is not appearing in listview initially

Tags: flutter, dart

At first, the list of publications was shown in ListTile. However, when I changed the String query, it doesn't show any data at all, and I can't search it. I want to show it as a ListView, but I want to hide it before searching and enter the correct title when I search, and I want to see what I searched. It's strange why suddenly a JSON file comes out.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyGetHttpData(),
  ));
}





class MyGetHttpData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyGetHttpDataState createState() => MyGetHttpDataState();
}

class MyGetHttpDataState extends State<MyGetHttpData> {

  String query = '유시민';
  int page = 1;

  String url;
  List data;

  Future<String> getJSONData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(url),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json" , 'Authorization' : 'KakaoAK 5a1167ba90ccb4b79d84ef5a41da0fbd'});
    //REST API 여기에 입력//
    print(response.body);

    setState(() {
      var dataConvertedToJSON = json.decode(response.body);
      data = dataConvertedToJSON['documents'];
    });

    return "Successfull";
  }
TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
        title: Text('widgettitle'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {

                },
                controller: editingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Search",
                    hintText: "Search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      data[index]['publisher'].toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black, ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

SharedPreferences prefs;
List<String> list;
// ...


Future<bool> _saveList() async {
  return await prefs.setStringList("key", list);
}

List<String> _getList() {
  return prefs.getStringList("key");
}


@override
void initState() {
  String query = '유시민';
  int page = 1;

  String url;
  List data;


  url = 'https://dapi.kakao.com/v3/search/book?sort=accuracy&target=title&size=10&query= $query &page= $page';

}
```

Comment: What has been fixed?

Comment: call your getJSONData() method on textfield's onchange property

Comment: It's not coming though ... Same thing.